# how to add dialog menu item from a file?

Tags: linux, shell, dialog

I'm writing a script in Linux, Until the user presses the zero button, the script will take filename and path from `dialog --input` (for example, in following format: `/etc/bob`), then it will list the locations for the user to select with `dialog --menu`. Then the user chooses an item in the menu, the script searches the file, and, if the file exists, the script copies the chosen file to user's home directory.

As of now, it throws `Error: Expected 2 arguments, found only 1`.

At first, the user enters a number of files he wants to search, so that number will be set in the `for` loop step and in `dialog --menu` as number of items (`$nu`). Then `dialog --inputbox` takes the user location and puts it in `loc`, then in `asd`; after that, in `db`. At the end, `dialog --menu` takes the line entry with `head` and `tail` from `db` file.

It works for one, sometimes 2, or even 4 items; but it then stops

Even when I put the `dialog --menu` out of the `for` loop, in the `while` loop- that doesn't work either.

How can I fix the problem?

```
wh=1
while [ $wh -ne 0 ]
do
dialog --inputbox "Please enter numbers of FILE you want to search" 8 60         2>/tmp/num
nu=`cat /tmp/num`

for i in `seq -w 1 $nu` #((i=1;i<=nu;i++));do

dialog --title "Search File" --inputbox "Please enter File name and Location in following Format to search .. [EX. /etc/passwd" 8 60 2> loc    #lo-$i
asd=`cat loc`
echo $asd >> db

dialog --menu "test" 15 50 $nu "1" `cat db | head -n 1`i "2" `cat db | head -n 2 | tail -n 1` "3" `cat db | head -n 3 | tail -n 2` 2>p 1>secl

done

done
```

Comment: Do you need it to use `dialog`? It can be done with `printf` and `for` and `while` loops pretty easy.

Comment: if possible with dialog why not. can you explain it with printf

Comment: Yeah, you can read the path with `dialog`, but it would be easier for you to read it with the `read` command, and print (hence the name) with `printf`. :)

Comment: The purpose of this script is the following (correct me if I'm wrong): Copy the files specified by the user to the `$HOME` directory. Am I right?

Comment: yes that's right. user give some file path name to the script let's say 4 5 path,when user press 0, process stops and list the paths for user then user chooses a path to search (find command) if the file exists the script copy that to $HOME.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "4 5 path"? I can't figure out what that means.

Comment: i mean 1-/etc/passed 2-/etc/shadow 3/usr/at.conf 4-/var/log ...check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

So far I came up this and everything is fine.but the problem is I can't figure it out how to figure what user typed and which file should I search for or find command search for.

I can check user input with 4 or 5 if,but what if user at the start of script enters 6 7 or 8 path?

please help - thanks in advance

[image: output so far]

```
clear

wh=1
while [ $wh -ne 0 ];do

    echo "Please enter FileName and Location to search for."
    read loc
    if [ $loc = 0 ];then
    wh=0
    fi
    echo "$loc" >> loc
done
clear
let lc=`wc -l < loc`-1
wz=`cat loc | head -n $lc`
echo "$wz" > eloc

while true;do
clear
echo "$(tput setaf 2)=====================================================================$(tput sgr 0)"
echo "$(tput setaf 2)========================== list of files ============================$(tput sgr 0)"
echo "$(tput setaf 2)=====================================================================$(tput sgr 0)"


for ((i=1;i<=$lc;i++));do
    echo -e " $i : "`cat eloc | head -n $i | tail -n 1` #print each line
    eval d$i=`cat eloc | head -n $i | tail -n 1` #put each line in a variable
done

echo "$(tput setaf 2)============================ q to exit ==============================$(tput sgr 0)"
echo "$(tput setaf 2)== if file is existed, will be copy to current user Home directory ==$(tput sgr 0)"

echo -e "\n"
echo -e "Enter your selection :\c"
read selec


#--------------------------------------------
if [[ "$selec" == q ]];then break; fi
#--------------------------------------------
if [[ "$selec" == "" ]];then
echo "$selec: not a valid selection."
continue
fi
#--------------------------------------------

echo -e "Press enter to continue \c"
read input
done

rm -Rf loc eloc
```